# Continue statement in Java

Tags: java, continue

I adding a continue statement to end the current iteration so that the rest of the statement in the loop body is not executed.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        while (number < 20) {
            number++;
            if (number == 10 || number == 11)
                continue;
            sum += number;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

The things I can't understand is why I will get error if I added `{}` ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        while (number < 20) {
            number++;
            if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
                continue;
                sum += number;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unreachable code

    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: It's obvious.  You can't get to sum += number;

Comment: @duffymo I want to understand the logic

Comment: How do you reach that line the way you wrote it?  Do you know how continue works?  What happens when you execute continue?

Comment: @duffymo The continue used to skip the `sum+=number`

Comment: Yes.  Why does the compiler complain?  When will it be executed?  What is that message telling you?

Comment: @duffymo From the answers below,I understand why now. Thanks.

Comment: Then please accept the answer that provided the best explanation for you.

Comment: @M.leRutte sure ..Have to wait one minute more :)

Comment: You are getting error using {} because when you are using these bracket your
sum+=number; statement is not executing because of above continue statement and without using bracket it works properly because if don't use {} bracket then condition works for next 1 line so that your
 sum+=number; statement executing properly that's why No error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
    continue;
}
sum += number;
```

**Explanation**

When you don't add `{}` to your `if` statement, only the next line will be considered. Therefore, you need to leave `sum += number` **outside** the `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Because continue statement is final in your branch (between {}), so next statement (sum += number) will not execute never. Your IDE must warn you of that, that's why it didn't compile it and you got error.

Answer (score 1):

In your first block, the one without `{` you effectively wrote:

```
if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
      continue;
}
sum += number;
```

The `sum += number` is reachable, as long as the expression is `false`.

In the second you actually wrote:

```
if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
       continue;
       sum += number;
}
```

The `sum += number`; has become unreachable because if the expression is `true` it will always be skipped because of the `continue`, and if the expression is `false` it will not be executed because it is not in the block statement.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers said correctly, only the first line of code will be run after an if statement. However, another rule is that you cannot add any more lines of code after the "continue" statement in an if statement.  So, that is really the error.  If you were to tweak the code to switch the "sum += number;" with continue, you won't receive the same error.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You execute `sum += number;` inside curly brackets (`{}`) of your if-block:

```
if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
    continue;
    sum += number;
}
```

This will work:

```
if (number == 10 || number == 11) {
    continue;
}
sum += number;
```